# How newline and paragraphs in forms gets converted into <p>,<br> etc?

Tags: jquery, html, flask

I have an input form to get comments from user which is send to server through ajax call with data in json format. The newline's are represented as \n in json. When I display the comment in the browser, comments are not skipping the newline character. If my understanding is correct, we have to convert this newline into 
 to display in the nextline.

Where I should do the replacement for \n to ? Before sending the comment to server or in the server while processing and saving the comment in to the db? My server is written in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you using `<textarea></textarea>` to send long text from web page, give it **`wrap='hard`** parameter, so it will include **`\n`** in the text when it wrapped or hard return (`ENTER` key).

In other side, when you retrieve the text, you can replace **`\n`** with **`<br>`** by using JavaScript or JQuery `replace()` method.

For example:

```
   var str = "test \n new line"; 
   var res = str.replace("\n", "<br>");
```